# Xcode Project Navigator is red

Tags: xcode, project-navigator

I have somehow made my Project Navigator red and I can't seem to find out how to get it back to normal.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

I'm using Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have tried googling the issue but I only seem to find the problem where the file name turns red which means the file can't be located by Xcode.

Comment: Is it possible that something being displayed behind Xcode has a lot of red in it? Your desktop or some other app maybe? Or perhaps you changed something in the macOS Settings app in the General or Desktop. Any 3rd party apps on your Mac that might let you change some color preferences?

Comment: @HangarRash I don't think that is it. Nothing is behind Xcode and nothing else in MacOS is red...
I think it happened after I accidentally tried to activate a breakpoint via a keyboard shortcut. Don't know which shortcut that might be.

Comment: This is expected behavior. All sidebars in macOS have translucency. If you want to mitigate there are two options: `Accessibility > Display > Reduce Transparency` (basically turns the effect off) & `Appearance > Allow wallpaper tinting in windows` (disables tinting on the chrome of every window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting macOS, without reopening windows, solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`control+cmd+f` does the trick, back and forth.

[image]